# How to implement phone Authentication using Firebase in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm developing Kotlin application using Firebase Phone Authentication. I'm confused on implementing this verifyphonenumber.

```
private fun startPhoneNumberVerification(phoneNumber: String, mCallbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks?) {
    Log.d("phoneNumber==", "" + phoneNumber);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this@LoginActivity,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks)
}
```

Implemented above code and getting error("None of the following functions can be called with the aruguments supplied") and also "creating extension function PhoneAuthProvider?.verifyPhoneNumber". Can someone Please guide me?

Comment: The timeout is a `long`, so `60` should probably be `60L`.

Comment: @Michael already tried. Still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of anything else so I'm assuming the Firebase callbacks parameter is annotated as nonnull.

TL;DR: remove the `?` from your callbacks parameter or no-op when it's null so Kotlin can do some magic type inference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sure the callback will not be null as you will initialise this in onCreate, declare it as

```
    lateinit var mCallbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
```

This works for me

Answer (score -1):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var btnLogin = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {view ->
            signIn(view,"user@company.com", "pass")
        }
    }

    fun signIn(view: View,email: String, password: String){
        showMessage(view,"Authenticating...")

        fbAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                var intent = Intent(this, LoggedInActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("id", fbAuth.currentUser?.email)
                startActivity(intent)

            }else{
                showMessage(view,"Error: ${task.exception?.message}")
            }
        })

    }

    fun showMessage(view:View, message: String){
        Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show()
    }

}
```